# Let $E \subset M$ and $x \in M$ then $x$ is a limit point of $E$ iff every $B_r(x)$ contains at least one point of $E$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

> Let $E \subset \left<M,\rho\right>$ and $x \in M$ then $x$ is a limit point of $E$ iff
>   every $B_r(x)$ contains at least one point of $E$

I am reading Methods of Real Analysis by Goldberg and I tried to prove the above theorem in my own words before looking at the proof in the book. My proof for the converse came out slightly different and I was wondering if it is correct.

**Book's proof for "$\impliedby$"**

Let $x \in M$ and suppose every $B_r(x)$ contains a point of $E$. Then for $n \in \mathbb{N}$, the open ball $B_{\frac{1}{n}}(x)$ contains a point $x_n \in E$. The sequence $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges to $x$ since $\rho(x, x_n) \lt \frac{1}{n}$, and hence $x$ is a limit point of $E$.

**My proof for "$\impliedby$"**

Let $\epsilon \gt 0$ be given.

Let $x \in M$ and every $B_r(x)$ contain a point of $E$. Then for $r=\epsilon$, $B_\epsilon(x)$ contains a point $y$ of $E$.

Define a sequence $\{y\}_{n=1}^{\infty} = \{y,y,...\}$, then $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, \rho(y_n,x) \lt \epsilon$.

So $x$ is a limit point of $E$.

Comment: What is your definition of a limit point?

Comment: Let A be a subset of M. Let x be in M. x is a limit point of A if there is a sequence $x_n$ in A such that it converges to x.

Comment: Ok. Your sequence of $y$’s does not converge to $x$ unless $y=x$, so your proof does not show that $x$ is a limit point of $E$.

Comment: Yes, $\{y,y,...\}$ obviously does not converge to $x$, but my hope was to always try to "fit" into the definition of convergence. That is, given any $\epsilon$ I can find $N \in \mathbb{N}$ sufficiently large enough so that distance between the points of sequence beyond $N$ and $x$ is less than $\epsilon$. So, is the mistake that I am making here is that I am trying to find a "sequence" that fits the definition? That is, I am not keeping the sequence fixed.

Comment: I’m not 100% sure what you mean. The mistake here is that you’ve found a sequence, but the sequence you’ve found doesn’t satisfy what you need from it to show that $x$ is a limit point. I think the biggest problem is that you’ve chosen a single $\epsilon$ to work with, which is an issue since the definition of convergence involves many $\epsilon$s. Try choosing a sequence of $\epsilon$s going to zero. Then you’ll find the sequence you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof for the converse part is not correct. Let $x$ be a limit point. Then there exists a sequence $(x_n)$ in $E$ converging to $x$. For any $\epsilon >0$ the ball $B(x,\epsilon)$  contains $x_n$ for $n$ sufficiently large , hence it contains at least one point of $E$.

Comment: I would like to understand why my proof is incorrect. Is the mistake that I am making is that I am picking a sequence that "fits" the definition of convergence rather than keeping the sequence fixed and finding $n$ sufficiently large?

Comment: $(y,y,..0$ is not  a sequence which converges to $x$. It converges to $y$. But you can vary $\epsilon$ in your argument and choose $y_n \in B_{1/n}(x)$ ($n=,1,2...$) and then say that $y_n \to x$. @Sunny